# How to implement a donation functionality?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm looking to implement a donation functionality with Drupal 8 Commerce. My question is if there is a solution for Drupal 8 similar to the one [Randy Fey described in his tutorial in 2011 for Drupal 7](https://vimeo.com/31460419)?

I'm basically looking for a donation amount picker to be used as the price of the product. I've got the order item type all configured so that people can pick their donation. 
What I'm missing now is how to set up the product pricing rule, that says: "ignore price field - use donation picker field instead".

The D8 module price rule https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_rule doesn't seem to do that. Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/bojanz/donation_example

Comment: Thank you, Bojan, it looks very promising. Will dive in.